# I have a question about memory management and the memory window from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, memory-management

Let's say I have this code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int a = 1633;
}
```

I put a breakpoint at line 4 so I can follow how the memory is allocated by using the Memory window from Visual Studio. I've noticed that when I plug in `&a` it will show this:

```
0x00CFF800  cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 61 06 00 00 cc cc cc cc 3c
```

I understand that my variable is that `61 06 00 00` because it's highlighted.

Questions:

1. Why do I have all of these elements at that address and not only `a : 61 06 00 00`?
2. Why is it written like that? I know that there are 4 bytes, but I don't know how to convert that code to my actual number. So, why is `61 06 00 00` equal to `a=1633`?

Comment: The number is *hexadecimal* 6*256 + 6*16 + 1 = 1633.

Answer (score 4):

> Why do I have all of these elements at that adress

You don't. VS shows you bytes adjacent to your variable as well.

The left-most `cc` is at address `0x00CFF800`, the next `cc` is at `0x00CFF801`, and so on.

> Why is a written like that?

Each pair of symbols represents one byte, the symbols are hexadecimal digits.

The bytes are arranged from least significant to most significant (the [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte order).

The easiest way to interpret the value is to:

- Reverse the byte order: `61 06 00 00` -> `00 00 06 61`
- Convert the resulting hexadecimal number to a decimal one: `00000661`(hex) -> `1633`(decimal)

This is equivalent to first converting each separate byte from hexadecimal to decimal: `97 6 0 0`, and then multiplying the values by powers of 256: `97 * 256^0 + 6 * 256^1 + 0 * 256^2 + 0 * 256^3  =  97 + 6 * 256`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhh now I understand why a byte is represent by a group of two element like 00... because FF=255 and also 1 full byte = 11111111= 255... So it's easier to represent things in hexadeciaml